# C++ beginner got 42

Tags: c++

Getting Douglas Adams vibes here...

I just started out with c++ and doing some code challenges right now.
The current challenge is to create a function that takes a number as its only argument and returns true if it's less than or equal to zero, otherwise return false.
However, when I run the program I get the number 42??

I actually don't need help for the challenge itself, I just wonder if someone could explain why I get this result :)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

bool lessThanOrEqualToZero(int num)
{

    if (num <= 0) {
        return true;
    }
}

int main()
{
    cout << lessThanOrEqualToZero(5);
}
```

[image]

Comment: What do you think your function returns if `num` is not less than or equal `0`?

Comment: Your program has undefined behavior - It could print `42` or `"galaxy"` or even some Vogon poetry. Also, `if(condition) return true; else return false;` can be rewritten to `return condition;`

Comment: A simple solution to fix your lack of returning a value when `false` would be to replace the body of the function with `return (num <= 0);` no need for an if () or an else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function `bool lessThanOrEqualToZero(int);`, as defined, makes your program have [undefined behavior](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ub) since not all paths in the function leads to the function returning a `bool` that you declared that it should return. Specifically: If `num > 0` is `true` the function doesn't return a value.

When a program has undefined behavior, you can't trust *anything* it does. Your program could therefore print just about anything or nothing, crash or do something completely wild.

In some compilator implementations, a value could be picked from the stack where it expects to find the promised `bool` and then print whatever that value was (42 in your case). The stack will then be corrupt. Other implementations may compile it into a program that does something completely different. You'll never know.

The solution is to make sure that all paths leads to a `return`:

```
bool lessThanOrEqualToZero(int num)
{
    if (num <= 0) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

This however better written as:

```
bool lessThanOrEqualToZero(int num)
{
    return num <= 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> otherwise return false

Well then you do need to return false otherwise.